# How do I delete data older than 7 days in CartoDB?

Tags: carto

I'm trying to delete data that's older than 7 days. I'm not sure how, though (no SQL experience). Everything I've tried to Google doesn't work.

The dates are formatted like "20200426" if that makes any difference.

Comment: If you want answer you need to give us more details (like data format, data field format, where it's stored, how do you access it,...)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to remove rows from a table where you have a date column as text (you should better store it in date format), you could do it from the SQL view of your table or from the [SQL API](https://carto.com/developers/sql-api/) by running something like:

```sql
DELETE FROM your_table where to_date(your_column,'YYYYMMDD') > current_date - interval '7' day;
```